# Signal Period of each stage in a ring oscillator

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, inverter

Considering the following ring oscillator:

[image: oscillator]
I know that the Frequency at \$Q\$ is given by 
$$f=\frac{1}{2*t_{PD}*3}$$
Yet I want to calculate the period of each signal at \$V_{1}\$,\$V_{2}\$, and \$V_{3}\$. Is there a formula to do so or am I just missing something?

Comment: They all have the same period, 1/f. The only difference is the phase. Unless I'm not understanding the question ...

Comment: What I wanted to ask is whether the formula for \$f\$ is valid only for the last stage or for all the stages at \$V_1\$, \$V_2\$, and \$V_3\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any oscillator, the period or frequency of the signal at *all* points in the feedback loop will be identical (unless the oscillator is using some multiplication or division technique to create a higher or lower frequency from a simpler oscillator). The signal may have a completely different phase, polarity, or waveform, but the period will be the same throughout.

In the particular case of a ring oscillator, consider this argument: you could tap the outputs of all three gates, producing three outputs instead of one, and then (ignoring any fanout/loading effects) the circuit would be completely symmetrical and therefore each stage is doing the same thing at different times.

If there *were* some signal in some design of oscillator that was at a different frequency (that's not in a deliberate simple ratio with it) it would either be completely irrelevant or making the oscillator more unstable (causing frequency modulation). At least, that's true as far as I know; I'd be interested to hear of examples to the contrary.